# How to Verify a method is called when I don't know what the parameter for the method will be in Moq

Tags: c#, moq

I need to verify that a method is called, however it receives a parameter object which I can't determine at design time. I don't care what the parameter is, I just want to verify that the method is called.

So I would like to call something like this:

```
        var subDao = new Mock<ISubscriptionSnapshotDao>();
        subDao.Verify(x => x.Save(), Times.Exactly(1));
```

However ISubscriptionSnapshotDao.Save takes an object to save.

```
 Save(Subscription entity);
```

Is there a way verify that Save has been called without knowing what the parameter will be?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is! If you know the Type of parameter the method expects.

```
It.IsAny<T>()
```

Try the following

```
subDao.Verify(x => x.Save(It.IsAny<Subscription>()), Times.Exactly(1));
```

Comment: No bother, Moq is awesome...you can select this as the "accepted" answer if you think its good enough!

Comment: Yeah was just waiting for the time limit, before I could tick it :-)